# docker buildx "exec user process caused: exec format error"

Tags: docker, rust, buildx

I am trying to cross-compile a rust app to run on my raspberry pi cluster. I saw buildx from docker was supposed to be able to make this possible. I have a minimal dockerfile right now, it is as follows:

```
FROM rust
RUN apt-get update
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "hello world"]
```

I try to compile this by running the command: `docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm/v7 some/repo:tag .`

when I do I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 0.9s (5/5) FINISHED                                      
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                  0.0s  => => transferring dockerfile: 102B                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/rust:latest                                                                                                                                        0.7s  => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/rust@sha256:65e254fff15478af71d342706b1e73b26fd883f3432813c129665a97a74e2278
0.0s  => ERROR [2/2] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                   0.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [2/2] RUN apt-get update:
#5 0.191 standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
------ error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update]: exit code: 1
```

I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic here, hoping for someone to tell me why such a simple thing isn't working for me.

I am running docker version 20.10.1 on a Ubuntu OS

Thanks in advance!

---

output of `docker buildx inspect --bootstrap`:

```
Name:   default
Driver: docker

Nodes:
Name:      default
Endpoint:  default
Status:    running
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/386
```

---

output of `ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`:

```
total 0
--w------- 1 root root 0 Dec 19 07:29 register
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 19 07:29 status
```

Comment: there is a typo: `apt-get upodate`. Should be `apt-get update` (in Step 2)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the error still remains the same without the typo, however :(

Comment: Please show result of `docker buildx inspect --bootstrap` and `ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To cross-compile requires `qemu-user-static` and `binfmt-support`.

```bash
$ sudo apt install -y qemu-user-static binfmt-support
```

`qemu-user-static` for user mode emulation of QEMU, and `binfmt_misc` for switching to QEMU when read other executable binary. Then, tell docker to use them.

```bash
$ docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
```

You must be afraid to run unknown image as privileged, but [the content is safe](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static/blob/master/containers/latest/register.sh). Next, create a user in docker for building images.

```bash
$ docker buildx create --name sofia # name as you like
$ docker buildx use sofia
$ docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
```

If you success, `buildkit` will be pulled:

```bash
[+] Building 9.4s (1/1) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                  
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                              9.4s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                           8.7s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_sofia0                                                                                                                             0.7s
Name:   sofia
Driver: docker-container

Nodes:
Name:      sofia0
Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Status:    running
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

Available targets expand!

Reference:
[Building Multi-Architecture Docker Images With Buildx | by Artur Klauser | Medium](https://medium.com/@artur.klauser/building-multi-architecture-docker-images-with-buildx-27d80f7e2408)

Comment: I'm on Fedora 33 and all I needed was `sudo dnf install -y qemu-user-static`. Thank you!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 and only `sudo apt install -y qemu-user-static binfmt-support` was required.  No need to run `multiarch/qemu-user-static` image.

Comment: Important to note that the "buildx create" and "buildx use" commands are non-optional. Steps for me became `apt install qemu-user-static binfmt-support` once, then `docker buildx create --name foobar && docker buildx use foobar` when I wanted to build.

Comment: I wished they mentioned this in the documentation (or is it too basic that it wasn't worth pointing out?)